Retrieve last state of model inside model itself?
I have some modules in my application and these modules are managed by a model called Module and their state is saved in database through this model.
Example Modules:
╔════╤═══════╤════════════╤══════════════╗
║ id │ title │ installed  │ dependencies ║
╠════╪═══════╪════════════╪══════════════╣
║ 1  │ A     │ false      │ ['B']        ║
╟────┼───────┼────────────┼──────────────╢
║ 2  │ B     │ false      │ []           ║
╚════╧═══════╧════════════╧══════════════╝

These modules are installed by a method called install(). When doing a clean installation, I retrieve all modules and then run $this->install() in a foreach loop.
$modules = Module::all();
foreach ($modules as $module)
{
       $module->install();
}

Before installation of each module, I first check if it is already installed and then check for dependencies of the module inside install() method and install them in a recursive way and after installation each module I update installed column to true but this attribute will not change in my $modules collection.
Imagine module A needs B first. B is installed in second level of my recursive method. When B is installed, the installed flag will be updated in my database, but the flag will stay the same in $modules collection and when installing B itself by traversing $modules the installed flag is still false.
Module.php:
class Module extends Model
{
    public function install(): void
    {
            // ** Maybe get last updated state here? **

            // Check if already installed
            if($this->installed) return;
            // Install dependencies first
            if($this->hasDependencies())
            {
                foreach ($this->dependencies as $dependency)
                {
                    $dependency->install();
                }
            }
            // Installation codes...
            $this->update([ 'installed' => true ]);
    }

One thing I have tried is getting the last state of model in my install() method by this code:
$this = self::where('id',$this->id)->first();

but I found out that it's impossible to reassign $this.
Any help from you is really appreciated.

you can just try $this->refresh() before checking if it was already installed which will reupdate all the fields from the database again but now it doesn't make sense to get ::all of the models from the start but you could just ::chunk(1) from the start https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent#chunking-results.
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent#refreshing-models

doing ::all because I want to install all modules on a clean installation. Anyway $this->refresh() is what I've been looking for. Thanks. Perhaps you could post it as an answer so I can accept. @LoaiAkram

You can use $this->refresh() to get all the attributes repopulated from the database. https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent#refreshing-models.
You can also use Module::chunk(1, function($module) {}) instead, which will retrieve all the records, 1 by 1 already fresh instead of using all and then needing to refresh each one again.
